# Where can I find a community that is dedicated to getting MacBook Pro laptops running Linux distributions, such as Ubuntu?

Tags: macbook-pro, unix

I have had some success in getting some 5-10 year old Mac computers running Ubuntu but nothing after 2018. I would very much like to join a group of hackers that make this process easier as I continue to see Apple MacBook Pro laptops as awesome hardware, especially now with the M1 CPU series. I know there are groups pursuing this goal but I do not know where to find them or how to connect with them.

Perhaps this community is a place to ask detailed questions such as, why does my late 2019 MBP get a Grub failure when installing Ubuntu 20.04.03?

Comment: The Unix & Linux stack?

Comment: Try looking [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358468/installing-ubuntu-on-macbook-2019-with-macos-big-sur).